# VBA Resize Array, 1 Column to 4 Columns

Tags: vba, excel

So I copied some data into Excel, but unfortunately for me when I pasted the data the chart format sorta died, so I ended up with a 1 column full of data(Column A). Basically A1 is suppose to be Movie name, A2 is suppose to be in B1(Cost of movie), A3 is suppose to be in C1(How long is the movie), and A4 is suppose to be in D1(Sequel:yes/no). And A5 is suppose to be in A2, A6 in B2, A7 in C2, A8 in D2, A9 in A3, A10 in B3..etc.. Its suppose to be a chart with 4 columns, but everything ended up in column A. Anyone can help me write a VBA code to rewrite the first column back to 4 columns? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read this article, it contains the answer to your question: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/split-a-column-of-text-HA103994003.aspx

Comment: Ill take a look now, and see if I can figure it out, thank you!

Comment: I read the article, and I don't want to break up a content of one cell, i just want to move it to another place. Like move A2 to B1, A3 to C1, A4 to D1, A5 to A2, A6 to B2...(making it 4 columns)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for VBA. In excel, use `INDIRECT` in the four columns

```
=indirect("A"&(row()-1)*4+1)  |  =indirect("A"&(row()-1)*4+2)  |  ...
=indirect("A"&(row()-1)*4+1)  |  =indirect("A"&(row()-1)*4+2)  |  ...
...
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This really helped me :) +1 kudos to you. I was just wondering the 2nd line is it suppose to be +3 and +4, to get the 3rd and 4th column? also how would i be able to use this function if I were to get it from another sheet? =indirect('Movies'!"A"&(row()-1)*4+1) seems to get an NAME error around the "A") I know I could just do it on the same page and copy & paste the values on another but was just curious on how to directly do it from another sheet, thanks :) :)

Comment: @user3784616, yes `+3` and `+4` to get the next 2 columns. `indirect` [works across sheets](http://www.contextures.com/xlFunctions05.html) too, you probably just had a typo.